# Burrow wheeler implementation for large strings

Tags: burrows-wheeler-transform

I have tried rotating a really large string in burrow wheelers cyclic string array.

But my input is about 200000 characters and when the input is this big i am unable to run the code as it runs out of heap space.

My prof said that the only way to implement it is Linear memory footprint. Which I have no clue what it means.

Can i Know what other ways to create a cyclic string which is memory efficient and use it without running out of memory

Comment: when the string is too big, you can either:

1. Perform operations externally (store shifts into a file and read in chunks in-memory). This involves rather messy I/O.

2. If you are on Java/C#, you can increase heap space as the default is not very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to reducing memory usage is to create a circular suffix array, which can be done in time proportional to `n lg n` in the average case (and memory proportional to `n`) using a variant of quicksort which considers each character in the string individually (aka 3-way String quicksort; it's conceptually similar to a radix sort).

When even that takes too much memory, you need to restrict your burrows-wheeler transform to operate on blocks of fixed size (perform the encoding on X characters, then the next X characters, etc until you've encoded the whole string, reversing the process for decoding).